# Is Humanity God's Idol?

Tags: israel, hosea, image-of-god

I just went down a rabbit hole of deep thought. I was listening to Joel Osteen and on his recent podcast. He seems to be advocating for prostitutes. By of course pointing to Rahab and the woman Jesus met by the well. Which aggravated me because I remember reading Hosea a while back and how much God was punishing Israel for loving prostitutes and them acting like prostitutes by whoring after other gods. While reading I was led to Hosea 13:2. In it, (tldr) it basically says that those who offer human sacrifices kiss calves and a little down it says no other God will be your savior but God (Jehovah, Yahweh, Adonai) etc.

My question then is. Since God offered Jesus Christ (A human sacrifice for man kind). Is Humanity an idol to God?

> Hos 13:2 - Now they sin more and more and make for themselves cast
> images, idols skillfully made from their silver, all of them the work
> of craftsmen. People say of them, “They offer human sacrifice and kiss
> the calves!”

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: The short and only answer is "NO".  Human sacrifices were offered to appease an angry God.  Humans are not gods and are not angry with Jehovah.  Therefore, your conclusion noes not follow.  God is Love, 1 John 4:8, 16.  The purpose of Jesus' sacrifice is explicitly stated in Rom 3:25-28 - Justice NOT appeasement!

Comment: This question suits better for ChristianitySE. Jesus sacrifice is a symbolic, ethical sacrifice, in the same way soldiers or firefighters sacrifice their lives to save others, or a father sacrifices himself for his family. It is not "human sacrifice" which is a ritual sacrifice of pagans to appease their gods.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: God in Greek ο θεοσ means a sight, look. A man, Adam άνθρ-ωπος ανθ - colour,light (as in flower) and ωπος to see, sight. Idol ειδωλο from ειδως-sight,form. Man made idols and icons to look at them and god (look) made men (watchers) to worship him. 
So there’s something to you hypothesis. You may want to look at these linguistic leads and add them to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Idolatry, by definition, is worship of something other than God. Man worshiped created things, but God has never engaged in false worship.

Romans 1:25

> For they exchanged the truth of God for falsehood, and worshiped and served the creature rather than the Creator, who is blessed forever. Amen.

When you worship worthless idols, you become darkened and foolish.

Psalm 155:8

> And those who make idols are just like them, as are all who trust in them.

God has always loved people and has never changed. Offering His Son for the world did not change or darken Him. This was not worship (i.e. idolatry) of fallen man, but He acted in love by becoming lowly like those He wanted to save from their fallen state.

Hebrews 13:8

> Jesus Christ is the same yesterday and today and forever.

Malachi 3:6

> For I the LORD change not...

John 3:16

> For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.

Answer (score 1):

No. God created man in His image and likeness (Genesis 1). Jesus Christ is the visible form of invisible God. We can conclude than that the humanity was made in His image and likeness. Just like, the earthly Tabernacle was a model of the Heavenly temple shown to Moses.
Israelites in the law were forbidden to make images of God because He already had one, us. So paradoxically, a man worshipping an idol is the true image of God worshipping a false one.
In the ancient Middle East, kings used to send their statues to the remote parts of their empires as everyday representatives for the subjects (like the golden image of Nebuchadnezzar in Daniel 3). Before that, God created humanity as His representatives here on earth.

As for the human sacrifices, God hates them. Jesus was not sacrificed by God. He willingly offered Himself as a substitute for others. A righteous one offering himself and suffering for the sins of others. Just like when His foreshadow, Moses offered his life for the people after the golden calf:

*The next day Moses said to the people, “You have committed a great sin. Now I will go up to the LORD; perhaps I can make atonement for your sin.”
So Moses returned to the LORD and said, “Oh, what a great sin these people have committed! They have made gods of gold for themselves.
Yet now, if You would only forgive their sin.... But if not, please blot me out of the book that You have written.”* (Exodus 32:30-32)

Comment: MY GOD, MY GOD, WHY HAVE YOU FORSAKEN ME?” Matthew 27:46

Comment: Going a little farther, he fell with his face to the ground and prayed, "My Father, if it is possible, may this cup be taken from me. Yet not as I will, but as you will." Matthew 26:39

Comment: 11 But Moses sought the favor of the Lord his God. “Lord,” he said, “why should your anger burn against your people, whom you brought out of Egypt with great power and a mighty hand? 
- 14 Then the Lord relented and did not bring on his people the disaster he had threatened. - Exodus 32:12-14

Comment: What you said is not backed by the scripture. In any way, God did sacrifice Christ, Christ didn't want to be sacrificed because he knew his current generation of the world was wicked and lackluster. Then Jesus answered and said, O faithless and perverse generation, how long shall I be with you? how long shall I suffer you? bring him hither to me.-
Matthew 17:17

Comment: Also we know that humans create and worship idols similar to their values and attributes. In the same way humans were created in the image of God. Humans were also crowned with God's spirit. "Worship" meaning showing admiration and respect for. Seems a little like God is worshipping humans by letting the sin & evil grow so large that the majority of cultural groups within the global population today is evil and corrupt. I hate I sound like this but I can't get over the way the world is currently moving right now.I'm wondering where are you God? Why does it seem like Humanity is an Idol to God

Comment: God Bowing Down To Humanity from what the scriptures say, seems eerily close to Worshipping Humanity. I know this sounds crazy, satanic, and evil to say. I know many won't understand where I'm coming from. However I'm putting this out there as a record for those who the one true God of Abraham, Issac, Jacob, David, and Christ will understand. Understanding in what these times of this generation show signs of.

Comment: Yes. People separated from God turn into what they worship. They become like the blind and dumb idols. They have eyes to see but do not see, and ears to hear but do not hear... It never changes. And they have a distorted perception of God, too. So God had to enter our world as a human to show us that He is love and what it means to be in His image.

Comment: So could you consider "love" as an idol in this case?

Comment: John 10:17-18 "For this reason the Father loves me, because I lay down my life that I may take it up again. No one takes it from me, but I lay it down of my own accord. I have authority to lay it down, and I have authority to take it up again." Jesus had a choice.

Comment: Before Jesus died though, Jesus "will" was not to get on the cross and die. Jesus however said let thy (God's) will be done. Matthew 26:39

Answer (score 1):

The OP question is not well tenable.

The human sacrifice of Hos 13:2 is in the form of;

- A human sacrifice another human to an idol in exchange the benefit of the first human

Whereas Jesus' crucifixion is

- Jesus sacrifice himself to His Father in redemption of human from their debt of sin.

Therefore they are not comparative.

Comment: You're right, human sacrificing another human is an abomination. Comparing human sacrifice of another , is different than God sacrificing Christ for us. God willingly came down,  showing what the holy will is for humanity. God knew humanity would kill Christ. However God did so, so that we would have an example of the perfect will of God for our lives.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, in a way, yet not idol but god, for God wants us to be like Him, like gods (Psalm 82:6), not by essence, according to which only the Father the Son and the H. Ghost are God, but according to participation in His grace and having divine life in us.

Thus, if He did not spare His Only Begotten Son for the sake of making us gods and made Him a sacrificial Lamb to bear our sins, then indeed He loves us to the point of deifying us, for the purpose of God’s love to us is nothing but making us as perfect as as He Himself is (Matthew 5:48), which He found possible only by the means of sacrificing His Only Begotten on our behalf.

So, yes, He adores and deifies - not idolizes - us through sacrifice of His Only Begotten.